# PhoneGap Android App Automation with Appium

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, junit, eclipse

I am using JUnit to make automation test , the context is changed to hybrid App , after tests I`m making output excel file with the result. I am new to the automation and found a way if something is not found and etc. to use try / catch block  to fill the excel file with the result . Everything looks that work like a charm I think ,but I have issue when there is a long Test Case ( with a lot of test steps) , if something goes to the "catch block" the test steps  in the excel file are marked as "Pass" after the "Fail" test step . Which I want to fix . Is there a way if some test step is marked as "FAIL" , all the other test steps under him to be marked also like "FAIL" or something like that .

```
public class LoginProcess extends Settings {
static SXSSFWorkbook workbook;
public static String[] columns = { "TestStep", "ExpectedResult", "Pass/Fail" };
public static List<TestCaseForExcel> testCases = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void BeforeTest() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    Capabilities();

}

@Test
public void TC_1_LoginProcess() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {


        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]")).isDisplayed();
            testCases.add(new TestCaseForExcel("Opened Customer application", "Splash screen opened", "PASS"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            testCases.add(new TestCaseForExcel("Opened Customer application", "Splash screen opened", "FAIL"));

        }

        // Click on Login Button
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.className("button-simple")).click();
            testCases.add(new TestCaseForExcel("Press Login button", "Login screen opened", "PASS"));
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            testCases.add(new TestCaseForExcel("Press Login button", "Login screen openedd", "FAIL"));

        }

}
```

In that case if the xpath is broken , and the element is not shown , the 2nd test step is written as "PASS" ,and its not even properly checked ,because of the first test step "FAIL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way if some test step is marked as "FAIL" , all the other test steps under him to be marked also like "FAIL" or something like that?

At the start of the test declare a boolean to serve as your flag and wrap each try catch.

```
var keepGoing = true;
if (keepGoing) {
    try {
        // your code
    } catch {
        // your code
        keepGoing = false;
    }
}
// rinse repeat
```

This gets the job done but I wouldn't call it a best practice. This is where Asserts came in. If you Assert a condition and it fails, the test method stops in its tracks (via throwing an Exception, which you would then log).

Comment: @It works , just  " keep going " must be boolean type not " var " in java , because variable cant be boolean type